# fast enumeration for array containing different types of objects

Tags: objective-c, fast-enumeration

If I have an NSMutableArray where I added objects of different classes (e.g. NSString, NSMutableString, NSProcessInfo, NSURL, NSMutableDictionary etc.) Now I want to fast enumerate this array, so I tried:

```
for (id *element in mutableArray){
   NSLog (@"Class Name: %@", [element class]);
   //do something else
}
```

I am getting a warning in Xcode saying

```
warning: invalid receiver type "id*"
```

How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is almost correct. When you use id, it's already implied to be a pointer, so you should write it as:

```
for (id element in mutableArray){
   NSLog (@"Class Name: %@", [element class]);
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: and you'd also probably want `[element className]` and not `[element class]`.

Comment: well class is also printing out the name correctly, however className makes more sense while reading the code ... thanks for the tip!

Comment: Actually, -className is not meant for this purpose. That method is meant for scripting integration in Cocoa. -[Class description] should provide the correct result, but if you want to be pedantic, NSStringFromClass([element class]) is more correct